# mongodb i/o timeout when using clustered mongo instances

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have an application that is using the `upper.io/db` package for communication with a Mongo database server (which is a fairly simple wrapper around `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`). The way the application works is that it creates a session in the main thread on start-up, and then each individual go routine that needs to make requests to the mongo server calls `Clone` on the session and does a `defer session.Close` on the resulting value. As far as I can tell, this is all standard operating procedure.

This setup works without any errors in our development environments where we are either using a locally run MongoDB *or* a sandbox instance on MongoLab. Recently we promoted the application up to our staging environment where we have the application talking to a Shared Cluster instance of MongoDB on MongoLab (the cheapest 15$ option). This is where the weirdness starts happening. The /first/ request that goes through (from the first go-routine that gets invoked) comes back with the expected response, but the subsequent ones all return

```
 read tcp <ip address>:47112: i/o timeout
```

This happens both from our local development machines pointed at the cluster or from the AWS host for the staging environment. Since the Mongo cluster is from Mongolabs I am going to assume that they've configured everything correctly on their end.

The code is somewhat boring TBH: It literally just opens the session in the main function and maintains a reference to it, and then there are multiple goroutines with this basic structure:

```
   sess := session.Clone()
   defer sess.Close()

   // make requests to Mongo
```

During testing, I even restricted it to run only one thing at once (i.e. only one goroutine is active at any given time), and it still fails in the same fashion.

Has anybody run into this before? Do I need to configure upper.io/db in a specific fashion? Maybe use mgo directly? I am at my wits end with this :(

Comment: They may have it configured correctly for within the cluster, but are the security groups and permissions within mongo set up to allow access from elsewhere? They probably have everything locked down, as they should.

Comment: Certainly I can make a connection to the cluster from the mongo cli client. And again, the first request to Mongo is answered successfully, its subsequent ones that timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a rather long and grueling process, we finally tracked down where this issue and similar ones like it came from in our program. It ended up being a session leak in the v1 version of the upper.io/db library. The bug and fix are [outlined here](https://github.com/upper/db/pull/212), but the v1 version of this library is horribly outdated at this point and the later versions do not exhibit this issue.

I doubt this answer will be useful for anybody so late in the game (especially since we ourselves solved it like.. 3 years ago at this point), but just wanted to leave the answer here for completeness.